# How to efficiently check text against a word list in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, algorithm, text

Given a text of 1,000 words, what is an efficient way to check against a dictionary of 10,000 words? I would like to count the number of non-unique matches.

One idea was to store the dictionary as a hash. But then I would have to check each word against the hash, which would be 1,000 operations. That doesn't seem efficient.

Another idea is Postgres text search. But is it possible to do this check in one query?

Another idea is to store the words in a Memcache or Redis database, but that would require 1,000 queries and be very slow.

So, is there a more efficient solution?

Working in Ruby.

EDIT: Add benchmarks for a :

Cary's assertion that `dict_set` is faster is true:

```
aw.length
=> 250
dw.length
=> 1233
dict_set.length
=> 1223
t = Time.now; 1000.times{ aw & dw }; Time.now - t
=> 0.682465
t = Time.now; 1000.times{ aw.count{ |w| dict_set.include? w }}; Time.now - t
=> 0.063375
```

So, `Set#include?` seems quite efficient.

Comment: Do you want to do this just once or for multiple texts of 1,000 words (with the same dictionary)? What do you mean by "non-unique" matches?

Comment: Is the 1,000 word set sorted?

Comment: @HenryChinner - Yes, the 1,000 word set can be sorted.

Comment: @CarySwoveland - Yes, I want to check many 1,000 word texts against the same dictionary. By non-unique, I mean suppose the word "awesome" appears twice in the text. If it appears in the dictionary, then the found word count would be increased by 2.

Comment: If "awesome" appears just once in the text and is in the dictionary is the count increased by 0 or 1?

Comment: @CarySwoveland - If "awesome" appears just once in the text and is in the dictionary then the count should increase by 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose:

```
text = "The quick brown fox and the quick brown bear jumped over the lazy dog"
```

and

```
dictionary = ["dog", "lazy", "quick", "sloth", "the"]
```

Let's first convert `dictionary` to a set:

```
require 'set'
dict_set = dictionary.to_set
  #=> #<Set: {"dog", "lazy", "quick", "sloth", "the"}>
```

and convert `text` to an array of downcased words:

```
words = text.downcase.split
  #=> ["the", "quick", "brown", "fox", "the", "and", "quick",
  #    "brown", "bear", "jumped", "over", "the", "lazy", "dog"]
```

Here are a couple of ways of counting the number of words in `text` that are in `dictionary`.

**#1: Simply count**

```
words.count { |w| dict_set.include?(w) }
  #=> 7
```

**#2: group same words and count**

```
words.group_by(&:itself).reduce(0) { |tot,(k,v)|
  tot + ((dict_set.include?(k)) ? v.size : 0) }  
  #=> 7
```

[Object#itself](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Object.html#method-i-itself) was introduced in v2.2. For earlier versions, replace:

```
group_by(&:itself)
```

with

```
group_by { |w| w }
```

The steps:

```
h = words.group_by(&:itself)
  #=> {"the"  =>["the", "the", "the"],
  #    "quick"=>["quick", "quick"],
  #    "brown"=>["brown", "brown"],
  #    "fox"=>["fox"],
  #    ...
  #    "dog"=>["dog"]} 
h.reduce(0) { |tot,(k,v)| tot + ((dict_set.include?(k)) ? v.size : 0) }
  #=> 7}
```

I would expect #1 to generally be fastest, considering that [Set#include?](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.0/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html#method-i-include-3F) is very fast. That is, I doubt that the time to group same words is less than the savings in dictionary look-ups.

Comment: Awesome! I didn't know that `&` would do it.

Comment: Hey, what happened to `&`?

Comment: `t&d` effectively steps through each element of `d` for each element of `t`. That's OK if you are doing it just once, but very inefficient if you are doing it multiples times for different `t`'s and the same `d`. In that case it's much more efficient to first convert `d` to a set (which is done under the covers with a hash), as set lookups are very fast.

Comment: I get `undefined method \`itself' for "A":String`. Which version of Ruby are you using?

Comment: Please see my edit. I meant to mention that ealier, but forgot to do so.